# SpriteKit, OK to leave a "sceneless" sprite hanging around?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

In all game dev you have prototypes in the scene editor,

[image]

here we have a model prototype of the "dog" unit and the model prototype for the "spaceship" unit.

Obviously you just disable them (or leave them offstage or whatever),

and at run time when you need a Dog you clone the prototype.

Generally speaking this all works great in the Apple setting with SpriteKit - terrific.  You'll have code something like ...

```
func setupModels() {
    
    modelDog = self.childNode(withName: "modelDot") as! SKSpriteNode
    modelSpaceship = self.childNode(withName: "modelBumper") as! ShipThing
}
```

Then you can clone them as needs be

But there is **one hang up**.

While you can `isHidden` a sprite, Apple really made no way to "utterly disable" a sprite, physics and all. *(NB, pls don't suggest "set the collision bits" - it's a model! heh)*

However I thought of a solution which (seems to) work fantastically, even though it seems strange ...

## .. just remove them from the scene (!)

```
    removeChildren(in: [modelDog, modelSpaceship])
```

WTF right?

This does seem to work perfectly. No, really, you can still clone them perfectly as normal during play.

- Am I bonkers, is there a problem here?
- Does everyone do this and my question is lame?
- Since 100.0% of games use models, does Apple have a "model" setting or such I missed??

Again, my question is ..

I have an SKSpriteNode.  I actually oddly remove it from the scene, it's just "sitting there" (it's .scene is nil).  Is this ok?

Comment: "model" is a 3D construct, not a 2D one,  and you should not leave nodes on scenes if you do not plan on using them.  You want to keep your tree neat and clean, with no cluttering leaves for optimal performance.  Remember,  this is not an ECS design like you have been thinking,  which a lot of game engines are.  You do not have a static entity construct sitting in memory ready to be copied and placed on the scene (Although nothing is stopping your from taking an ECS style approach)

Comment: (sorry for the confusion, not "3d mesh model" I just mean a "model" - like a prototype. (an "original" you copy from.)  100% of 2D games use such models, you clone them to spawn)

Comment: "You want to keep your tree neat and clean, with no cluttering leaves for optimal performance" right - notice I'm saying that (bizarrely) I am *removing it from* the scene.  it is just existing "nowhere"  :)  strikes me as weird, but it seems to work

Comment: I know, I am telling you that it is what you are suppose to do.  Also, no, 100% of 2d games do not do this approach,  2D game engines sure, but I never heard of them referred to as “models”. Sprites or prefabs.  You can always create 1 scene used for extracting nodes, and another for visual representation